# Unable to get an output for share percentage

Tags: sql, formula

I need a help with a query to find out the total share of Loyalty Transactions from Store Transactions

Loyalty transactions are transactions where the customer uses a loyalty card,When this happens,this transaction is marked as a Loyalty Transaction.

All transaction details,whether normal transaction(non-loyalty) or loyalty transactions are recorded into the transaction table

The formula is for a filtered date..
total count of all Loyalty transactions / total count of all transactions(Including loyalty transactions) x 100 %

This is my query

```
select 
    [Loyalty_Share] = ((select count([Transaction No_]) 
                        from [ABC Store$Transaction Header] 
                        where [Customer Disc_ Group] = 'LOYALTY' 
                          and Date = '01-Jun-2018') /
                       (select count([Transaction No_]) 
                        from [ABC Store$Transaction Header] 
                        where Date = '01-Jun-2018')) * 100
from 
    [ABC Store$Transaction Header]
where 
    Date = '01-Jun-2018'
```

I am looking for a single row that gives me a result in %
like for instance 34.04%

My Query gives me multiple rows all with 0's,similar to this

Loyalty_Share

```
0 
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

How can I correct the query so I get a single row,one result and the format as XX.XX %

Appreciate all the help

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the division of integers.  But you can radically simplify the query using conditional aggregation:

```
select avg(case when Customer Disc_ Group = 'LOYALTY' then 100.0 else 0 end) as Loyalty_Share
from [ABC Store$Transaction Header]
where Date = '01-Jun-2018';
```

If `Date` is stored using a date/time data type, then you should use standard formats for the constants -- `'2018-06-01'`.